# How to get AFRAME desktop view on mobile no headset

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm creating an embedded aframe scene. On desktop it loads in the desktop view where I can use WASD and move around. On mobile it turns into the VR headset mode. I want on mobile for it to display as if were on desktop, with no headset attached. Thanks!